# Scala String type ambiguity

Tags: scala, generics

I want to drop some elements in scala Seq, but get confusing error:

```
<console>:33: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[java.lang.String]
 required: Seq[String(in method drop_Val_List_In_List)]
           tmp;
           ^
```

What is `Seq[String(in method drop_Val_List_In_List)]`?

The code is below:

```
// Method that drops one element in sequence
def drop_Val_In_List[A](ls: Seq[A], value: A):  Seq[A] = {
    val index = ls.indexOf(value)  //index is -1 if there is no matc
    if (index < 0) {
        ls
    } else if (index == 0) {
        ls.tail
    } else {
        // splitAt keeps the matching element in the second group
        val (a, b) = ls.splitAt(index)
        a ++ b.tail
    }
}

val KeepCols = Seq("id", "type", "month", "car", "road")


// Generalization of the above method to drop multiple elements
def drop_Val_List_In_List[String](ls: Seq[String], in_ls: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
    var tmp = ls
    //println(tmp.getClass)
    for(x <- in_ls ){ // should work without var x
        tmp = drop_Val_In_List(tmp.toSeq, x.toString)
    }
    tmp;
}

val tmp = drop_Val_List_In_List(KeepCols, List("id", "type", "month"))
```

The desired output: tmp that contains  "car" and "road" strings

Comment: side-note: `def drop_Val_List_In_List[A](ls: Seq[A], in_ls: Seq[A]) = ls.foldLeft(in_ls)((tmp, next) => drop_Val_In_List(tmp, next))` is the short version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`def drop_Val_List_In_List[String]` declares a type parameter that you call `String` that shadows the "real" `String`.

If you want to do it for any type `A`, change the `String` there to `A`. If you want to specialize for `String` only, remove `[String]`, and keep `def drop_Val_List_In_List(...)`

Answer (score -2):

I changed some types, now it works

```
def drop_Val_In_List[String](ls: Seq[String], value: String):  Seq[String] = {
    val index = ls.indexOf(value)  //index is -1 if there is no matc
    if (index < 0) {
        ls
    } else if (index == 0) {
        ls.tail
    } else {
        // splitAt keeps the matching element in the second group
        val (a, b) = ls.splitAt(index)
        a ++ b.tail
    }
}


def drop_Val_List_In_List[String](ls: Seq[String], in_ls: Seq[String]): Seq[String] = {
    var tmp_ = ls
    //println(tmp.getClass)
    for(x <- in_ls ){ // should work without var x
        println(x)
        tmp_ = drop_Val_In_List(tmp_, x)
    } 
    tmp_
}
val KeepCols = Seq("ctn", "type", "month", "car", "road")
val tmp = drop_Val_List_In_List(KeepCols, List("ctn", "type", "month"))// Start writing your ScalaFiddle code here
println(tmp)
// Start writing your ScalaFiddle code here
```